# Publishing a Form to a Form Library is not Allowed

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have been assigned a task to check out an InfoPath 2010 form that is located within a Form Library.

For testing purposes I created a new Form Library called Test Form Library.

I then publish the form to the site below:

[image]

However, when I click next I don't get the option to publish to the Test Form Library I created shown below:

[image]

I have never come across this and wondering what the issue is.

Can someone clear the air for me?

Answer (score 0):

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262921(v=office.14).aspx)

> Form templates have different administrator requirements depending on
>   the way they use code and connect to data.
>
> Many form templates in InfoPath Forms Services in Microsoft SharePoint
>   Server 2010 can be uploaded by users without being individually
>   approved by an administrator. These form templates are called “user
>   form templates.”
>
> Form templates that contain business logic driven by managed code,
>   access data from external resources, or use data connections that are
>   managed by an administrator must be granted trust to execute code and
>   access data. This trust comes in two forms:
>
> - Sandboxed solutions
> - Administrator-approved form templates

In this [article](http://sharepointblogbyshri.blogspot.com.ar/2013/10/an-administrator-must-approve-this-form.html) you have info about the steps to solve this situation:

> Now let’s move to “Sharpeoint Central Administration” to approve the
>   published form template by the administrator and Activate it on Site
>   Collection
>
> - Open Sharepoint Central Administration >> Application Management >> In “InfoPath Forms Services” section click “Manage form templates”
> - Upload Form Template >> Select the published form template from the physical location used above  (Do not change other default settings on
>     this page) >> Click “Ok”
> - In Manage Form Templates list, Right click newly added infopath form template item and activate it to the desired site collection by
>     clicking “Activate to site collection” link. This will activate a
>     feature on site collection level and would add it to the “Form
>     Templates” library. You can check whether the feature is activated by
>     going into that site collection features section and also you can
>     verify whether published template is added to the “Form Templates”
>     library or not.